# DataInterval: как определить наступила ли дата или нет?

Tags: php

Имеется string вида '2016-07-25 18:14:00' Как определить наступила ли дата или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2016-07-25 18:14:00');
$now = new DateTime();
if($date < $now) echo 'Дата наступила';
echo 'Дата не наступила';
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться функцией `strtotime`которая приведет вашу строку в метку времени Unix, и дальше сравнить полученный результат с результатом полученным от функции `time()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now->diff('дата');

if($diff->invert)
 //прошедшее время
else
 //будущее время
```